# Django/Webpack - How to serve generated webpack bundles with webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, python, django, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Django's 'static' tag generates urls using STATIC_URL, which results in something like '/static/myapp/js/bundle.js'
Mean while, webpack-dev-server is serving bundles from the url 'localhost:3000'

My question is how do I get Django 'static' template tag to generate a different url ( which points to webpack dev server) for js bundles. Of course I can hardcode it in the template, but that would not be a good solution.

Below is my project configuration

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')


module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    context: path.dirname(path.resolve(__dirname)),
    entry: {
        index: './typescript_src/index.ts',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./myproject/assets/myapp/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new BundleTracker({filename: './myproject/webpack-stats.json'})
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: '/myapp/bundles/',
        // hot: true,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8000", /**Django dev server */
        }
    }
}
```

settings.py

```py
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': not DEBUG,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'myapp/bundles/', # must end with slash
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map']
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

Initially I decided webpack should serve other static files as well during development

webpack.config.js

```js
devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: '/myapp/bundles/',
        contentBase: path.resolve('./myproject/assets')
        // hot: true,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://127.0.0.1:8000", /**Django dev server */
        }
```

settings.py

```py
# in development mode serve from wepack dev server
if DEBUG:
    STATIC_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

But I later realized I have to serve static files of other apps (admin, tinymce, ...), which is impossible for webpack Dev server to reach

The problem here is that the url generated by 'render_bundle' tag of django-webpack-loader (/static/myapp/bundles/bundle-name.js) will result in a Http 404 because webpack-dev-server keeps the generated bundle in memory and not on disk

Also if I set

```py
STATIC_URL = localhost:3000
```

and configure webpack-dev-server to serve other static files of my app, static files of other apps won't be served

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's analyze the issue:

We have 2 servers and we want to route requests to one or the other based on the path requested:

`"/static/webpackbundles/** ==> webpack dev server`

`other paths ==> django dev server`

This is exactly the job of a proxy server, it can be achieved with a third server (haproxy, nginx ...), but that might seem like an overkill, especially if we know that `webpack dev server` can be used as a proxy! (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: '/path/to/django_project/django_project/static/webpackbundles',
    publicPath: '/static/webpackbundles/',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '/path/to/django_project/django_project/static/webpackbundles',
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '!/static/webpackbundles/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8000', // points to django dev server
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

In your django template:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'webpackbundles/main.js' %}"></script>
```

Now access your django app/site using `webpack dev server` address:
ex: `http://localhost:8081`

With this simple config you'll have browser auto refresh and hot module replacement.
You will not need to change anything in django, also no need for django-webpack-loader

Comment: Your solution is nice and it works, thanks. But we will still need django-webpack-loader to render the correct bundle names, since generated bundle names are in the form of [name]-[hash].js. Of course if we do not add the [hash] part to the bundle names, we could do without django-webpack-loader.

Comment: No need to add hashes with webpack, django can do it (which will ensure that non-webpack static files also have hashes), just add this to your django settings file: `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'` (See [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage)). This will save you the hassle of adding/maintaining an extra django package.

Comment: Did not know about ManifestStaticFilesStorage. But looking at the docs, it seems it requires DEBUG=False, and other requirements. This still makes me think it will be more natural if webpack do the adding hashes part. But still good to know Django has that. It might come in handy some other time

Comment: You can also use [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) which creates html files with webpack bundles (js, css ...) automatically injected in them, these files can be extended from a django base.html templates, and also can be extended further to create your final django pages templates. See [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/pull/1234#issuecomment-546675413) and  [here](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/issues/209) , this is I think a lot better solution than using django-webpack-loader. @myke

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ejez answer, i was able to configure webpack-dev-server to serve all static files (including, media files)

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    // project root (usually package.json dir)
    context: path.dirname(path.resolve(__dirname)),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./path/to/bundles/'), 
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new BundleTracker({filename: '/path/to/webpack-stats.json'})
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name: 'lib'  // bundle all their party libraries in lib.js
        }
    },
    devServer: {
    // if you do not mind webpack serving static files of other apps
    // collect them (with django collectstatic) into /static_root/static/ 
    // this way webpack-dev-server can serve from your own app's /static/
    // directory and also /static_root/static/ directory (which contains
    // static files of other apps
        contentBase: [path.resolve('./project'), path.resolve('./project/static_root')],

        // webpack bundles will be served from http://locahost:3000/static/project/bundles/
        publicPath: '/static/project/bundles/',

        port: 3000,

        // proxy all request except (static and media files) to django dev server
        proxy: [{
            context: ['**', '!/static/**', '!/media/**'],
            target: 'http://localhost:8000',
            changeOrigin: true,
        }]
    }
}
```

Now you can access your project from webpack-dev-server url `localhost:3000`. Do not forget to start both dev servers (webpack and django)

Comment: This seems a little inefficient for rapid development, as you would need to collectstatic each time you modify your non-webpack static files. Why not keep things simple and let webpack-dev-server serve only webpack stuff, and proxy requests to django stuff to django dev server.

Comment: Yh it will be if you will have to collectstatic each time you change static files in your app. But i meant to collect them once to have access to static files of other apps, and each time to install a third party app (which happens occasionally).

Answer (score 0):

Is generally not justified using STATICFILES_DIRS,
instead use STATIC_ROOT.
If You have permission to copy static files to the project folder then use STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).